# I have Problem with AJAX post using laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am working on simple private chat application ,when i send message to selected user so message is sending perfectly but meassage is showing  on browser  relaod i have used ajax but unfortunatly ajax is not working please help me thanks.

**Controller**

```
             public function chataction(REQUEST $request)
             {   
             $chat_message = $request->get('message');
             $from_user_id=Auth::user()->id;
             $to_user_id =$request->get('myid');                  
             $user = Auth::user();
             $response = $user->Chats()->create([             

             'chat_message'=>  $chat_message,
             'from_user_id' => $from_user_id,
             'to_user_id'  => $to_user_id,
              ]);    
             $response = array(
              'status' => 'success',
              'msg' => 'Setting created successfully',
              );
              return Response::json($response);  

              }
```

**html view**

```
          <!-- /.card-body -->
          <div class="card-footer">
          <form id="myform" action="{{route('chat.action')}}" method="post">
          {{csrf_field()}}
          <input type="hidden" name="myid" value="{{$single_chat->id}}" >
          <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" id="chatmessage" name="message" placeholder="Type Message 
          ..." class="form-control">
          <span class="input-group-append">
          <button type="submit" name="btnsubmit" id="btnsubmit"  class="btn btn- 
          primary">Send</button>
          </span>
          </div>
          </form>
          </div>
          <!-- /.card-footer-->
         </div>
```

**Ajax**

```
             <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function() {

             $("#btnsubmit").click(function(){
             event.preventDefault();
             var form_data = $("#chatmessage").val();
             $.ajax({
             url:"{{ route('chat.action') }}",
              data:   {
              "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
              "form_data": form_data
              }
             dataType:"json",
             success:function(data)
            {

            }

            });
            });
            });

            </script>
```

**Route**

```
        Route::post('chat/action','HomeController@chataction')->name('chat.action');
```

Comment: So, does your ajax work or does it not? Might want to take a look at [broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/master/broadcasting) to update/refresh client pages whenever chat changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the .reload() method inside an Ajax success callback function.

```
success:function(data)
{
   setInterval('location.reload()', 3000); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your `javascript` code is wrong.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $("#btnsubmit").click(function(){
     event.preventDefault();
     var form_data = $("#myform").serialize();
     $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       url:"{{ route('chat.action') }}",
       data: form_data,
      dataType:"json",
      success:function(data)
      {

      }

    });
   });
 });
</script>
```